# GraphViz - maintain digraph alignment when adding disjunctive edges

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I am attempting to generate a directed graph.

My current graph.c code in DOT language:

```
digraph G {

rankdir = LR;
splines = line;

subgraph start{
start -> J0M0;
start -> J1M2;
start -> J2M0;
start -> J3M0;
}

subgraph J0 {
    J0M0 -> J0M1;
    J0M1 -> J0M2;
    J0M2 -> J0M3;
}

subgraph J1 {
    J1M2 -> J1M0;
    J1M0 -> J1M1;
    J1M1 -> J1M3;
}

subgraph J2 {
    J2M0 -> J2M1;
    J2M1 -> J2M2;
    J2M2 -> J2M3;
}

subgraph J3 {
    J3M0 -> J3M2;
    J3M2 -> J3M3;
    J3M3 -> J3M1;
}

{rank=same;}

J1M3 -> JE;
J0M3 -> JE;
J2M3 -> JE;
J3M1 -> JE;

 //    J0M0 -> J2M0;
 //    J0M1 -> J2M1;
 //    J0M3 -> J2M3;
 //    J1M2 -> J0M2;
 //    J2M0 -> J3M0;
 //    J2M1 -> J3M1;
 //    J2M2 -> J1M2;
 //    J2M3 ->J1M3;
 //    J3M0 -> J1M0;
 //    J3M2 -> J2M2;
 //    J3M3 -> J0M3;
 //    J3M1 -> J1M1;
}
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image: Directed Graph Only Conjunctive Edges]

My aim is to include the commented out edges however adding them causes the graph to lose it's alignment and end up all over the place.

The goal is something like this:

[image: Disjunctive Graph]

Can anybody help in explaining the useful graphviz/dot attribute so i can add the disjunctive arcs without breaking alignment of the conjunctive arcs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- Use `group` to suggest a straight line of all nodes of each subgraph (nodes with same group are layed out in a straight line if possible)
- Use `constraint=false` for the 'disjunctive' edges
- And of course `splines=false` for smooth edges

Resulting in:

```
digraph G {

rankdir = LR;
splines = true;
start;
JE;

J0M0[group=a];
J1M2[group=b];
J2M0[group=c];
J3M0[group=d];

subgraph start{
start -> J0M0;
start -> J1M2;
start -> J2M0;
start -> J3M0;
}

node[group=a];
subgraph J0 {
    J0M0 -> J0M1;
    J0M1 -> J0M2;
    J0M2 -> J0M3;
}

node[group=b];
subgraph J1 {
    J1M2 -> J1M0;
    J1M0 -> J1M1;
    J1M1 -> J1M3;
}

node[group=c];
subgraph J2 {
    J2M0 -> J2M1;
    J2M1 -> J2M2;
    J2M2 -> J2M3;
}

node[group=d];
subgraph J3 {
    J3M0 -> J3M2;
    J3M2 -> J3M3;
    J3M3 -> J3M1;
}

{rank=same;}

J1M3 -> JE;
J0M3 -> JE;
J2M3 -> JE;
J3M1 -> JE;

edge[constraint=false];
     J0M0 -> J2M0;
     J0M1 -> J2M1;
     J0M3 -> J2M3;
     J1M2 -> J0M2;
     J2M0 -> J3M0;
     J2M1 -> J3M1;
     J2M2 -> J1M2;
     J2M3 ->J1M3;
     J3M0 -> J1M0;
     J3M2 -> J2M2;
     J3M3 -> J0M3;
     J3M1 -> J1M1;
}
```

Comment: constraint=false was the cure. Thank you!